# Best approach for sending message to multiple connected users by using aws websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, chat

I am building a chat application similar to **Telegram**. Let's say 1 million members are in a group and if someone sends a message in that group, everyone should get the message instantly.

In my project I am using dynamodb for storing user & message details and AWS Lambda for querying data from dynamodb and API Gateway for websocket connection. Is there any possibility that lambda function will be closed before the query & sending the message to all the connected users? If so, what will be the alternative approach?

Flow Explanation:

1. Once the lambda function gets a group message from client/frontend, It will store the data in dynamodb.
2. After that I will read all the websocket connected users from another table. (eg. connections)
3. Finally I send the message to all the users one by one through the websocket.

I've deployed my project in **us-east-1** region.

If my approach is not a scalable or recommended way of creating a group chat application. Please suggest any other approaches.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.